# Cannot find glib-gettext. in msys2

Tags: msys2

I am running an autogen.sh script under MSYS 2.

I installed all requested packages so far, but

```
checking for glib-gettext >= 2.2.0...
testing glib-gettextize... not found.
```

I don't get.

A package named `glib-getext` doesn't exist.

I run:

```
pacman -S glib2
```

but without success.

I also run:

```
$ pacman -S gettext
```

in hope that would solve my problem, but it doesn't.

What should I do with `glib-gettext`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is

```
pacman -S glib2-devel
```